# How to reference a dynamodb stream arn from an existing table in cloudformation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cloudformation

I have a dynamodb table in one region (Singapore) which was created by a global table from another region (Sydney). So there is no cloudformation stack for the table in Singapore region. I am going to deploy a lambda which enable streams from the table in Singapore. The question is how can I reference the stream arn in the cloudformation when I deploy the lambda?

Comment: Sorry, your question is not clear. Do you have any example of CFN template to show?

Answer (score 1):

There's two main approaches:

1. Pass the Stream ARN as a parameter to the CloudFormation stack when you create it
2. Write a Custom Resource (Lambda-function) to query the Stream ARN and return it. Then write your actual Lambda trigger based on the output of the custom resource